# Bad access error when trying to set or get an instance variable

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to make a scene where you drag labels into the correct boxes. But I get a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, dress = 0x107867618)" error whenever I try to access the labelInside variable of any of my boxes, either to set it or retrieve it. Ive tried checking for deallocation with zombies but found nothing. Ive also tried removing the getter and setter and just simply setting it to one of the labels, but even then it crashes on retrieval. From my research I think it might be a corrupt pointer, or the class isn't initialising properly, but I'm completely stuck on how to fix it. My code for the class "LabelBox" and the function that it crashes on are below. Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you.

```
    class LabelBox:UIView {
        let correctLabel:UILabel? = nil
        var labelInside:UILabel? {
            get {
                return self.labelInside ?? nil
            }
            set(newLabel) {

                newLabel?.center = self.center
            }
        }
        var containsCorrectLabel:Bool {
            get {
                return correctLabel == labelInside
            }
        }
     }        



    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch:UITouch! = touches.first as UITouch!
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        print(box1.correctLabel) //this works
        //print(box1.labelInside) //crashes when trying to get, even if value set to a label
        if let label = labelTouching {
             if let box = checkPointInBox(location) {
                box.labelInside = label //crashes when trying to set
            }
        }
        labelTouching = nil
    }

    func checkPointInBox(location: CGPoint) -> LabelBox? {
         let boxes = [box1, box2, box3]
         for box in boxes {
             if CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, location){
                 return box
             }
         }
         return nil
     }
```

Comment: correctLabel is nil with "let", means it's immutable, means it's ALWAYS a nil

Comment: Thanks, didn't spot that. Now that I've changed it I get a similar BAD_ACCESS error when trying to access correctLabel as well

Answer (score 1):

Look at how you defined the `setter` of `labelInside`

```
var labelInside:UILabel? {
    get {
        return self.labelInside ?? nil
    }
    set(newLabel) {
        labelInside?.center.x += 20
        self.labelInside = newLabel // this cause an infinite loop!
        self.labelInside!.center = self.center
    }
}
```

This means that, later on, when you write `box.labelInside = label` the setter is executed

But inside the setter you have

```
self.labelInside = newLabel
```

This produces another call to the setter that, again, executes

```
self.labelInside = newLabel
```

that does produce another call to the setter... this loop never ends.

Just remove this line from your setter.

```
self.labelInside = newLabel
```

### Fixing #2

There's another error in you code, now it's not causing a crash but in future it could.

This line

```
self.labelInside!.center = self.center
```

should be changed as below

```
self.labelInside?.center = self.center
```

### <s>Fixing #3</s>

Ok, please try updating your setter as below

```
set(newLabel) {
    newLabel?.center.x += 20 // this line is useless and can be removed
    newLabel?.center = self.center
}
```

### Fixing #4

Please remove the current `labelInside` property (getter and setter included) and replace with this.

```
var labelInside:UILabel? {
    didSet(newLabel) {
        newLabel?.center = self.center
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand the infinite loop and have removed it, however I still get the same error. I've also changed the correctLabel to be a variable, I mistakenly set it as a constant, however I also now get a BAD_ACCESS error when accessing it as well

Comment: its the same as above, I just removed the line causing the infinite loop. I think i misunderstood exactly how setters work with the newValue, so ill have to change it to get it working as intended. However at the moment it seems that whenever I try to access an instance variable of the class I get a bad access error, which I don't get if I change the variable to a constant

Comment: Please update the code in question to match exactly the code you are using now. Next: what do you mean with accessing? Reading or writing? Show me the exact code otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: OK, I've updated the code above. I've tried reading and writing, both result in the same bad access error

Comment: Please replace this `self.labelInside!.center = self.center` with this `self.labelInside?.center = self.center`

Comment: OK, I've made those changes

Comment: @Neyth1: I added a new paragraph **Fixing #3** to my answer, let me know if it does fix the problem.

Comment: Still the same error i'm afraid. I also get the error when trying to read or write to the correctLabel and containsCorrectLabel variables as well, so I don't know if the class is not being initialised properly or something?

Comment: Writing self.labelInside ?? nil is rather pointless. You are basically saying "if self.labelInside is nil then return nil instead of nil".

Comment: @Neyth1: please try my Fixing #4

Comment: Unfortunately hasn't helped

Comment: Unbelievable, can you show me the current full code for `LabelBox` and the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @Neyth1: are you sure you updated the declaration of `labelInside` exactly as I indicated in `Fixing #4`? Did you remove the old `getter`?

Comment: yes, i've checked, its not just that variable though, trying to access any of them crashes the program

Comment: Are you using some `!` where the program does crash? In my Playground everything does work. I'm afraid there is some more code not present in this post.